# Can someone open React components only meant for authenticated users

Tags: reactjs

So I am creating this react app and i was wondering if anyone can gain access to the components only meant for the authenticated users by using the chrome dev tools somehow.

If yes, how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: You need server-side access control.

Comment: @SLaks I am using google's firebase to authenticate the users. By server-side access you mean, I should provide the private component files from the server?

Comment: No; I mean you should make sure your server can never send data that users should not see.

Comment: @SLaks So like I have a database setup, i should make sure the front end has no private data and only send when an authenticated user requests it. Tell me if i am thinking wrong.

Answer (score 1):

sure, you need to create a state boolean variable and then ask if true show component:

```
{this.state.isAutenticated && <RenderMe />}
```

or

```
{this.state.isAutenticated ? <RenderMe /> : <RenderDummy>}
```

Comment: And even if someone messes with the front end logic, my backend should only send data for the state in components/containers when the authentication validates them. Am I getting that right Ariel?

Comment: of course, the back-end should handle its own authentication permission logic, normally using token autentication and then validating in each request that the user  autenticated has permission to access that data